# Is it possible Notepad++ to change the theme based on current filetype

Tags: notepad++, themes, syntax-highlighting, color-theme

For example, if I open a text file, notepad++ would open it in 'default' theme. But if I open a php file for instance, it would open it in 'custom_theme1'. I know notepad++ is highly extensible, so I wasn't sure if anybody had ever run across a plugin that could do it. Or could a plugin even be written to do this?

Comment: how different should the theme be? you can specify your User-Defined language and apply it

Comment: @petr marek The theme that I want is a custom one that I've added and I am certainly able to manually go to Settings > Style Configurator and choose from the theme drop down list. You said "you can specify your User-Defined language and apply it" > do you have an example how to do that? Sounds like it could provide a possible answer to my question.

Comment: Select Language from the menu bar and click User-defined. A floating window will open. http://screencast.com/t/jO6oBPaD

Comment: @peter marek Right I get that, but what I want to do is if I open a php file, I want it to automagically change the editor's theme to a different one (a darker one), but if I open a text file, I want it to change the theme to default. I'm not using any custom defined languages. Sorry if my original question was confusing.

Comment: It appears this feature is not a part of notepad++ but has been put in as a feature request. See here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/321/

Comment: @avagailliot yes it appears that way. If you would, put that into an answer and I'll accept it as it appears this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time it appears that this functionality is not a part of Notepad++. However, it has been submitted to the developers as a feature request.

> Let Language style change theme, or global bg colour 
> Written by
>   yakumo-unr the 5 Dec 10 at 01:23. 
>   I would like for a language
>   definition to be allowed to change the global theme for when that
>   language is loaded, and/or at the very least change the global
>   background colour.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/321/